# Copy text from LibreOffice Writer to text file using terminal

Tags: ssh

I am connecting to my Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS Server via ssh.

And I want to view my LibreOffice Writer Notes remotely.

I need a way to copy text paragraphs from .odt files to a normal text file.

This way I can read customer reports uploaded via our support web application without the need to download all the .odt files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a tip that will fits your needs  :

First :

Install **abiword**.

```
sudo apt-get install abiword
```

Second  the following command:

```
abiword --to=txt /pathofyour/file.odt
```

This command will copy all the text from `file.odt, and create automatically`file.txt` file in the same directory then paste this text.

If you want to view reports, then just use `cat file.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unoconv`. To install via `apt` use,

```
sudo apt-get install unoconv
```

To convert a `.odt` file to `.txt` file use in terminal,

```
unoconv --format=txt file.odt
```

Your converted txt file name will be `file.txt` at the same location.